# How to write simple static analysis using Swift?

Tags: swift

How do I implement a static analysis using Swift that warns the users if their Swift program has a function that has more than 3 parameters? For example:

```
func Lst(name: String, age: Int, address: String, date: String){}
```

the static analysis should raise a warning about this function and tells the users what type are the parameters. Should I write a parser using Swift for this? Or is there any swift library that allows me to read another .swift file?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mayday](https://github.com/marklarr/mayday) you can catch the line and check if this line is function definition then parse it and count the number of parameters.

This library works build time and acts like the XCode warnings and errors.